# InvalidCastException when casting FrameworkElement.ToolTip to System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip

Tags: wpf, tooltip, .net

I need to makes some changes to a `ToolTip` programmatically.  That sounds simple enough.  Well, apparently not really. :/

I have a `ToolTip` on a `WindowsFormsHost` object and I make the following cast to get to the `IsOpen` property:

```
((System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip)host.ToolTip).IsOpen = true;
```

This line fails during runtime with an `InvalidCastException`.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip'.

I don't understand why this is failing.  I must be missing some thing terribly simple as this code apparently works just fine in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/844f3b03-d1bc-402e-9760-5355aaddf30f/) example.  @_@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToolTip` is not by accident of Type `object` and not `ToolTip`. If you set the `ToolTip` in XAML like this `ToolTip="Test"` then your ToolTip is of type String. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltip.aspx). To modify your tooltip, i would suggest not using it in code directly, instead use the power of XAML and DataBinding. If you insist doing it in code, create an actual ToolTip for the property.

Comment: I wished I could take advantage of databinding, but in this situation it won't work. :( Thanks for the answer!